# Jest Async tests are confusing me

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jestjs, angular-spectator

Here is the scenario:

Using Jest/Spectator to test RXJS observable but can't seem to get to the line of code I want to test via my current setup

Component code -

```
  ngOnInit(): void {  
    this.authDetail$ = this.validateToken(this.token).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
      catchError((error) => { 
        if (error) {
          // I want to test this next line...
          // But I never see it run...
          this.router.navigate(['unauthorized'], { replaceUrl: true });
        }
        // This only exists to satisfy the observable chain.
        return of({} as SomeModel);
      }),
    );
  }

  validateToken(token: string): Observable<SomeModel> {
    return this.authService.lookupByToken(token);
  }
```

Test-

```
  it('should redirect to "unauthorized" when error is thrown', (done) => {

      jest.spyOn(spectator.component, 'validateToken')
        .mockReturnValue(throwError({ status: 403 }) as any);

      spectator.component.validateToken('invalid_token').subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
          console.log('NEXT BLOCK: Should Have Thrown Error');
          done();
        },
        error: (error) => {
          expect(spectator.router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            ['unauthorized'],
            { replaceUrl: true },
          );
          expect(error).toBeTruthy(); 
          done();
        },
      });

      // This fires off the ngOnInit :)
      spectator.setRouteParam('token', 'INVALID_TOKEN');
    });
```

The issue I am having is that when the test runs I can see that I am receiving a 403 but the router.navigate is not being called. If I console.log that part of the subscribe block, in the component, I see that it's never reached.

How do I test that line of code?

Comment: Inside of the `catchError`, if you `console.log(error)`, what do you get?

Comment: @AliF50 I get a ```{status: 403}```

I see the error I mock but I don't know if I am suppose to see the router call in my component or if its just to test if I catch the error from the mock. Confused at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see your problem.

If you have:

```
catchError((error) => { 
        if (error) {
          // I want to test this next line...
          // But I never see it run...
          this.router.navigate(['unauthorized'], { replaceUrl: true });
        }
        // This only exists to satisfy the observable chain.
        return of({} as SomeModel);
      }),
```

The `return of(..` will make it go to the success block and not the error block when you subscribe to that RxJS stream because the `catchError` is saying if there is an error, handle it this way and return this (`of(..`) for the stream.

I see you're expecting the navigate call in the error part of the stream.

I would try changing the test to this:

```
it('should redirect to "unauthorized" when error is thrown', (done) => {

      jest.spyOn(spectator.component, 'validateToken')
        .mockReturnValue(throwError({ status: 403 }) as any);

      // This fires off the ngOnInit :)
      spectator.setRouteParam('token', 'INVALID_TOKEN');
      // subscribe to authDetail$ after it has been defined in ngOnInit
      spectator.component.authDetail$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe({
         next: (result) => {
           expect(spectator.router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            ['unauthorized'],
            { replaceUrl: true },
          );
          expect(result).toBeTruthy();
          done();
         }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Well done!!!! This totally fixed my issue! Thanks for your help :D